# Problem running phpunit on a windows machine

Tags: windows, php, installation, zend-server

Hello I am trying to get phpunit to work on my windows machine.
I have Zend Server CE installed and i Installed pear. But when i do:

```
phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml
```

I get the error:

```
phpunit is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is phpunit in your PATH?

if not you can set it in:

```
Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced (tab) > Environment Variables
```

Append the directory where phpunit.exe lives to the Path variable. Make sure you don't omit the ; before you enter the path. ie, you would add something like:

```
;c:\Program Files\App\
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have installed it through pear. But phpunit.exe can not be found. I tried to search for it with windows search.

Comment: Did you try to search for phpunit only without extension ".exe"?